# missing 1 required positional argument dt

Tags: python, kivy

i want to just display each increment of count on the label with the help of this
kivy.clock package

```
class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    count=0
    def my_callback(self):
        global count
        count +=1
        us= self.ids.tet

        if count == 10:
            us.text=count
            return False
        print("call back is called")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 1)

  count +=1
```

NameError: name 'count' is not defined

Comment: Why you define dt in my_callback()? it's no use

Comment: ohh thanks i have tried it by removing it but i got new error  NameError: name 'count' is not defined

Comment: you must define "count=0" outside  can use "global count" in your function

Comment: sorry for doing this i am new to stackoverflow  i want to show u my full code so plz wate i am editing it

Comment: now i have this error :(

Comment: you need define count outside the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Button Binding - on_press / on_release event

> How can i bind my_callback function to button event

### Solution - Button on_press event

The following snippets show how to bind `on_press` event to a callback.

#### Snippets - kv file

```
Button:
    text: 'Invoke method'
    on_press: root.btn_callback(self)
```

#### Snippets - py file

```
def btn_callback(self, instance):
    print(f"\nButton.text={instance.text}")
```

## Using Kivy Clock - invoke callback() method

When using [Kivy Clock object](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) to schedule a call to a method without using `lambda` function, you must declare a positional argument, `dt` (means delta-time).

### Snippets

```
def my_callback(dt):
    print(dt)

Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 1)    # call callback every 1 second
```

or

```
def my_callback():
    print("my_callback called")

Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: callback(), 1)    # call callback every 1 second
```

## Example

The following example illustrates displaying a counter defined as a class attribute.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<MainWindow>:
    Label:
        id: tet
        font_size: sp(50)
    Button:
        text: 'Invoke method'
        on_press: root.btn_callback(self)
""")


class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    count = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 1)

    def my_callback(self, dt):
        print(f"my_callback is called: count={self.count}, dt={dt}")
        self.count += 1

        if self.count == 10:
            self.ids.tet.text = str(self.count)

    def btn_callback(self, instance):
        print(f"\nButton.text={instance.text}\n")


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks you  :) , one more question ,How can i bind my_callback function to button event i have tried it but it giving error when i press button : TypeError: my_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dt'

Comment: Please refer to updated post for binding button's `on_press` to a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def my_callback(self):
        global count
        count +=1
        us= self.ids.tet

        if count == 10:
            us.text=count
            return False
        print("call back is called")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 1)

count = 0
```

You have to define `count=0` outside the class that you are creating and by saying `global count`, you are making this variable global, which means that now your function can edit the variable in the global scope. You should google more about scoping if you want to learn it.

[This might be helpful to begin with.](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)